# Host my own DNS

Tags: dns

I brought few domain names from a domain register in my Country. So yea they manage the domain like change DNS etc. Is there a way that I can mange my own DNS.

Example:

Domain Register (DNS) points ---> DNS Manager Service (This is where I will manage the DNS) from my side. It will like a redirecting DNS just like we redirecting websites from one domain to another.

Hope you understand what am trying to say here. I don't whats its called. Did Google but even a clue what am looking for.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a managed DNS service.

There is a nice list [on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_managed_DNS_providers)

Once you acquire one of these services, you will inform your domain register to point to the managed DNS site.  Any request for your domains is forwarded to the managed DNS site.  You will use a control panel on the managed site to further forward to your final destination (rented cloud server, server at home, construction page, etc)